# DB2 maximum value for DATE column

Tags: sql, date, db2

I've tried to update the value of date column to **2040-04-14** but the value became **2001-01-01**?

When update to some nearer date for example **2013-01-29** then everything works fine?

```
Update policyTable set maturitydate = '2040-04-14' where policynumber='999';
```

Comment: [This IBM reference](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPEK_10.0.0/com.ibm.db2z10.doc.intro/src/tpc/db2z_datetimetimestamp.dita) suggests you should be good as far as `9999-12-31`, but I speculate that earlier versions of DB2 might fail at 2038AD

Comment: silly question, but why do you need 2040 dates?

Comment: @MitchWheat: because 25-year mortgages mature in 2040; 40-year mortgages have been beyond that for 15 years.

Comment: Maybe you should show the code you used to update the value.  There are a lot of ways to get things wrong.  And dates tend to cause more trouble than other types.

Comment: What version and platform of DB2?

Comment: In addition to the version and platform of DB2, please describe any client drivers/APIs that are involved in sending the UPDATE statement to DB2. Assuming MATURITYDATE is defined in DB2 as a DATE column, it's possible that a client API could be causing the Y2038 problem by using a 32-bit integer to store the date value.

Answer (score 0):

If this issue happens from 2038-01-20, you have the 2YK38 error and you must to upgrade your db2 database to fix it.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Year_2038_problem

If you have this error when you try to insert a value before 1940 or after 2039, you must to change the host connection appending ";date format=iso".

https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/date-values-written-null-db2-ios-rbd-data-perspective

Regards!